# How to create SEO Friendly URL

Tags: php

I have passed in the href link as follows

```
<a href='http://ukbestweb-live.co.uk/trends/products/<?php echo $resGroup[id]; ?>/<?php echo str_replace(" ","-",trim($resGroup[group_name])); ?>'>$resGroup[group_name];</a>
```

My .htaccess code is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ products.php?group_id=$1&gcat=$2
```

So how can I convert the url "http://ukbestweb-live.co.uk/trends/products.php?group_id=7&group_name=Designer-Lighting" to "http://ukbestweb-live.co.uk/trends/group/Designer-Lighting"

For above seo friendly URL what should be my href link? And what should be the .htaccess?

Comment: you can check wordpress for same refer its permalinks and you have better idea how to deal with such situation

Comment: DO not do as @JanakPrajapati suggested. Google rewrite urls php and apache (or whatever webserver you use).

Comment: This project is Developed in PHP not in wordpress framework.I need the solution in htaccess